# Builder (Context) in Builder cannot be applied to (Context, java.lang.String)

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-messages

Всем привет,делаю уведомления,в классе `NotificationUtils` получаю такую ошибку.

```
Builder (Context) in Builder cannot be applied to (Context, java.lang.String)
```

Строка с ошибкой

```
final NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext, CHANNEL_ID);
```

**CHANNEL_ID -** `private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "myChannel";`

Что это и как можно вылечить?В другом проекте оно работает нормально.
Если убрать **CHANNEL_ID** уведомления приходят,но не открывается активность,где должен писаться текст уведомления.

Импорты

```
  import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.media.Ringtone;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.text.Html;

import com.whrsmxmx.vk_api_test.MapsActivity;
import com.whrsmxmx.vk_api_test.PushTest;
import com.whrsmxmx.vk_api_test.R;
import com.whrsmxmx.vk_api_test.vo.NotificationVO;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
```

Build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
    implementation 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4'
    compile 'com.vk:androidsdk:1.6.5'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.9'
    //Новый хлам от уведомлений и т.д
    implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

Comment: Навскидку: может у вас импорты разные? И билдеры с разных суппорт библиотек

Comment: @Jarvis_J я добавил в пост импорты и gradle, честно не очень понимаю что надо)

Comment: CHANNEL_ID работает с версии android api level 26. Нужно делать проверку на версию.

Comment: @ValeraKvip ,не подскажите как это сделать?Я в этом не очень понимаю..

Comment: Создай Builder без channelID, а потом проверь if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {  builder.setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID );}. ПС: мне негде проверить, но у себя я так сделал. Ну и еще конечно нужно создать канал. https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification#Priority

Comment: Не думаю что активность не открывается из-за этого. Скорее всего ошибка в другом месте.

Comment: @ValeraKvip ну я думаю да,не в этом дело,но и это тоже меня смущает)Хотя уведомления приходят

Comment: Они и будут приходить, а вот открываться не факт. Без когда создания уведомления ничего не сказать. А про channelIs таки почитайте, все равно внедрять придется.

Comment: @ValeraKvip https://pastebin.com/XH9mpHdy вот полный код самого кода этого
С channel честно не понял в итоге...ибо в другом моем проекте,этот же код полностью работает...

Comment: У Вас же нет второго параметра в 97-ой строке

Comment: @woesss я пытался убрать Channel там,по этому нет.С ним ошибка выше

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решился этими строками...

```
implementation "com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.0.0"
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.0'
```